# When the ionic picker is opened the individual column items all stack on top of each other

Tags: ionic4

The issue is explain here. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19222

The ionic picker stack items on top of each other, when you click on it the second time on wards.

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.7 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.8.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
@angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v12.4.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.4.0/bin/node)
npm    : 6.11.2
OS     : macOS Mojave
```

This is the code https://github.com/NomiJ/ionic-picker-styling-issue

[image]

Comment: what is your cordova version?

Comment: no cordova installed

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17664

```
await picker.present();
picker.onDidDismiss().then(async data => {
  picker.columns.forEach(col => {
    col.options.forEach(el => {
      delete el.selected;
      delete el.duration;
      delete el.transform;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a workaround to fix this issue.

**Step 1:** Don't use `await` for `picker.present().`

**Step 2:** Use Query Selector to get the column view element by class name

```
const pickerColumn = document.querySelector('.picker-columns') as HTMLElement;
```

**Step 3:** Reduce the opacity of the element to `0`

```
pickerColumn.style.opacity = '0';
```

**Step 4:** Add transition, so that the rendering will be smooth

```
pickerColumn.style.transition = 'ease-in-out 0.1s';
```

**Step 5:** Bring back the opacity to `1`, after `300ms`

```
setTimeout(() => {
  pickerColumn.style.opacity = '1';
}, 300);
```

**Here's the final code**

```
picker.present();
const pickerColumn = document.querySelector('.picker-columns') as HTMLElement;
pickerColumn.style.opacity = '0';
pickerColumn.style.transition = 'ease-in-out 0.1s';
setTimeout(() => {
  pickerColumn.style.opacity = '1';
}, 300);
```

Hope this helps!

And it seems this issue has been fixed in Ionic 6 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24366

But, I am still using Ionic 5. So, I am using this workaround only and it works for me.